# Gmail search keywords to get all unread messages

Tags: gmail

Is there a way to search for all unread message in Gmail?

The closest I have found is searching for `is:unread`. I am not sure if it's a Gmail bug or if my syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Your `is:unread` syntax is correct. It's a known Google issue.

[Google support link](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=29403539a86bbe9b)

Comment: mmh the link you provided seems to be an issue about the unread count

Comment: Oh - misread.  Rather than "in", I think you need "source" e.g. source:buzz is:unread